# WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION triggers every time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I have this `BroadcastReceiver` implementation in my `Fragment` :

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo =
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                    if(networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                         //do stuff
                    }
                    //Other actions implementation
            } 
       }
};
```

With standart register/unregister methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, getIntentFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver); 
    }
```

And receiver with same implementation for `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` in other `Fragment`

***The issue:*** this action triggers everytime one of the fragments started, but i need it to trigger only if Wifi was really just connected, and as the name of action says `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`, so it should work only if **Wifi state changes**

**Edit:** as was replied this action will trigger every time by the default, so my question is: There is no action for *Wifi connecting* ?

Comment: I think a better option would be to just have one BroadcastReceiver in the Activity, and call methods in the currently active Fragment when a connection state change occurs.

Answer (score 3):

That's how the WifiManager works when you register for NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION. When you register it, you will get 1 update immediately, to show the current state.

To circumvent this, you could have a simple boolean in your fragment set as default to 'true'. In your broadcast receiver, check if this is true, and if so, it's the first time you get an update, set it to false and then simply ignore the update. The next time it's called, the boolean will be true and you can use the data.

```
    private boolean firstTime = true;

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(firstTime) {
                    firstTime = false;
                    return;
                }

                if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo =
                            intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                        if(networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                             //do stuff
                        }
                        //Other actions implementation
                } 
           }
    };
```

Comment: I can't do it, because i'm switching between two fragments and at least one of them will be recreated each time. So there is none actions for __Wifi connecting__ ?

Answer (score 3):

The NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION broadcast is likely "sticky", use the isInitialStickyBroadcast method check if the broadcast is the first "sticky" one:

```
@Override
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (!isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
    // Only check updates in state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See ["ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html). This is only available in API 21 onward. This may not have the exact condition you are after, but is close.